# Load Balancing Tomcat Servers while keeping a single Session ID

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, mod-jk

I want to be able to Load Balance two Tomcat servers, that are broadcasting Session Data to one another, using Apache and mod_jk.

I've set up the Load Balancer and that works perfectly, however, I'm currently having to use `sticky_sessions` to make this work. I want to be able to set `sticky_sessions` to `false`, and be able to only use a single Session ID to be sent to either Tomcat server.

Is there any specific config needed to make this possible, or is it even possible?

Here is my `worker.properties` file:

```
worker.list=jkstatus, jkmanager, LoadBalancer

worker.jkstatus.type=status
worker.jkmanager.type=status
worker.LoadBalancer.type=lb

worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=TOMCAT-1-IP
worker.worker1.port=8009

worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.host=TOMCAT-2-IP
worker.worker2.port=8009

worker.LoadBalancer.balance_workers=worker2,worker1
worker.LoadBalancer.sticky_session=0
```

I have also set up jvmRoutes in each tomcat instance, as '`worker1`' and '`worker2`', like I said, with the `sticky_session` set to '`1`' this works, but I'm forced to use one Tomcat for the duration of that session which I don't want.

I need to be able to go to any Tomcat with a single Session ID, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have enabled a DeltaManager for session replication?

Comment: Yes, I have `<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>` under my Cluster parameter in server.xml

Comment: You only need to set sticky_session=0 (restart apache) and add the <distributable /> flag to your web.xml. Session id will be suffixed with the Tomcats node name.

Comment: I've added the <distributable /> flag, and I'm getting the right traffic from the server, what I want is for both Tomcats to work without the Tomcat node name appended on the end the Session ID, is there a way Apache can just route to any Tomcat without the Session ID having the node name on the end?

Comment: Guess not but why not splitting off the '.node' suffix where needed?

Comment: I've managed to get it up and running now, I didn't have my Tomcats set up properly to broadcast sessions to one another, I was running one Tomcat 6 and one Tomcat 7 without be aware of their versions.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about the value of the session id itself?